# Deja-dup asks for administrator authentication

Tags: permissions, backup, authentication, deja-dup

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, installed and managed by my workplace.
I have set up backup on my home folder only, each day.

Regardless, an authentication dialogue is opened each time:
"Authentication is needed to run '/usr/libexec/deja-dup/duplicity' as the super user". I have to cancel this manually each day as I do not have root access.

That script has permissions "rwxr-xr-x" and I can look at it (as expected). It should be possible to execute it also according to the permissions, at least.

How should I get rid of this annoying authentication, and do I have a backup, I wonder?